# From Byte to String Conversion using Encoding.ASCII ,get null ended value there after using trim() not remove this null .

Tags: c#, string

Within string remove first or last null spaces.used this `trim()`,`trimEnd()`,`trim("\n","\t")` etc but not removed null.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: You want to replace `null`, or `NUL`, or `\n` and `\t`? There is no such thing as *null spaces*. It is totally unclear what you actually want to do. Some code would be useful here.

Comment: `Trim`method return new "trimmed" valued - not updating value you calling method with

Comment: string ProductName = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recData, 34, 20);

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not assigning `value back` to the `textbox` after `Trim()`.

Only calling function `Trim()` or `TrimEnd()` will not take effect until you assign back it to `textbox`

```
string str = " This is a string ";
txtBox.Text = str.Trim();
```

You can also check for empty or null using `IsNullOrEmpty`

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
{
 //Console.WriteLine("string is either null or empty");
}
```

Comment: Looks from where? - OP has no code :)

Comment: @Fabio i have seen question like this many times and people do this mistake don't assign back the value otherwise C# is good enough to call its methods

Comment: I guess Fabio meant we don't like guessing. I could think of a dozen reasons why the code fails, but without code it is hard to really give a conclusive answer.

Comment: thanks for suggestion , but not working for null.

Comment: @user3729201 please see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you  Mairaj .

Comment: @user3729201 is your issue resolved ?

Comment: Yes ,Solved  using   str.TrimEnd(new char[] { (char)0 }); Thnaks.